# Парсер матчей dota 2

Tags: парсер

Откуда парсят статистику матчей `Dota2`?
Как пример - сайт [dotabuff](http://ru.dotabuff.com/matches)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

Answer (score 3):

Существует Dota 2 Match History WebAPI http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=47115

Comment: Там так же есть информация по других играх? Например CS:GO

Comment: @tekken нет, CS:GO там нет. TF2 есть.